# Solve Heat Equation with Source Term and Neumann BC

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find a solution on mathematica to

> $ \partial_tu-\partial_{xx}u= \cos(2\pi x), \; 0<x<1,\; t>0  $
>
> $ \partial_xu(0,t)=\partial_xu(1,t)=0, \; t>0 $
>
> $ u(x,0) = \sin^2(3\pi x), \; 0 \leq x \leq 1 $

to be able to check my answers when working them out by hand.
I have tried several methods, two of which I will list here:

- Method 1

  ```
  sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == Cos[2 \[Pi] x], Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0 , u[0, x] == Sin[3 \[Pi] x]^2}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];
  ```

This gives me an output of an interpolating function. Is there any way to get an explicit answer?

- Method 2

  ```
  eqn = D[u[x,t],t]-D[D[u[x,t],x],x]==Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
  BC1 = D[u[x,t],t]/.x->0==0;
  BC2 = D[u[x,t],t]/.x->1==0;
  IC = u[x,0]==Sin[3\[Pi]x]^2;
  DSolve[{eqn,BC1,BC2,IC},u[x,t],{x,t}]
  ```

  However, I do not think I am using the right functions to solve this. DSolve, NDSolve? any suggestions would be very welcome. I am trying to read up on their website how to solve PDEs.

Thank you

Comment: There are typos in method 1; try `sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
    Cos[2 \[Pi] x], Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0 , 
   u[0, x] == Sin[3 \[Pi] x]^2}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i get                                                          
      NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.                           NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.                     u-> interpolating function scalar hermite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] - D[u[x, t], x, x] == Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
bcs = Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 0;
ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[3 \[Pi] x]^2;
sol = DSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]